# CPU Usage of the Process on the Server

Tags: deep-learning, operating-system, gpu, cpu-usage

Why the case that there's a process which starts to run early occupying much more (like 10x) CPU usage than other processes which run later, always happens? Is there any priority policy of the server system to do with this phenomenon?

[One example on the multi-GPU system server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnpIN.png)

Thank you!

Comment: And do u guys know how to alleviate or solve this kinda problem?

Comment: Additionally, for the pic above, there're 90+ CPUs (many of them are used less than a half) and ~400 G Mem (20+ G left available) on a 4-GPU server.